# Common Lisp Pause Command inside a Loop

Tags: matlab, lisp, common-lisp

Is it possible to have a command in common lisp which somehow temporarily pauses the execution. In matlab you can achieve this by using the pause command, in which you can also set the time to pause as well. What I want to do is that, in a loop I will print my result to the top-level then wait for x-seconds (I am going to set the x), do the next iteration, print and wait and so on.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [SLEEP](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_sleep.htm).

Comment: To see some output in portable CL it might also be useful to call FINISH-OUTPUT before calling SLEEP.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use SLIME, interrupt the execution of the program and
eval an expression in frame to modify the value of some variables « by hands »
or use the exceptions system and provide a restart which will ask to the
user the new values.